# Default style for custom html tags

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular 1.4 and to prepare for the release of Angular 2, I am converting all my directives to use `restrict: 'E'` tag instead of `restrict: 'A'`

But in doing this, I seem to have to add each custom tag to my sass file, and state that I want to treat it as though it was a div element, then display:block and other bootstrap defaults are used.

Is there a way I can do this without having to add each custom tag to my sass file, like more of a global setting?

Comment: Hm... I bet you could decorate all directives to apply a default style to any element with restrict: 'E'. It might be way more work than just putting a selector in your css that contains all new elements, but it may work. :)

Answer (score 0):

All your directives could add some attribute like eg `custom-element`.

then you can target all DOM elements with that attribute, like this:

```
[custom-element]: {
 display: block;
}
```